# How to make text, that is in variable, bold using pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I basically have a variable that contains the string. This is not a fixed string and is being changed by the user, so every time user uses the bot - string changes. My question is how to send a message from the bot to the user making text in variable bold?

For example, my code is

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Your number is — " + "<b>" + str(text) + "</b>", parse_mode='HTML')
```

What I expect to see is

Your number is - **204566234**

How can it be done in PyTelegramBotAPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bold: **Hello**

```
from telebot import formatting

bot.send_message(
    message.chat.id,
    formatting.hbold('Hello'),
    parse_mode='HTML'
)
```

italic:*Hello*

```
formatting.hitalic('Hello')
```

underline: H̲e̲l̲l̲o̲:

```
formatting.hunderline('Hello')
```

strikethrough: <strike>Hello</strike>:

```
formatting.hstrikethrough('Hello')
```

code: `Hello`

```
formatting.hcode('Hello')
```

If you want parse Markdown, just change `parse_mode` and replace `m` with `h`:

```
...
formatting.mbold('Hello'),
parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
...
```

You can see good examples [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/formatting_example.py).

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'formatting' from 'telebot'`

Comment: Oh, I just updated telebot and it works!

Comment: Nice! enjoy with bot.